# Две равноправные нормы ударения – это правильно?

Tags: ударение

ВОПРОС 1.  Две равноправные нормы

На форуме неоднократно обсуждались темы, связанные с правильностью ударения. В частности, говорилось о том, что существование двух норм – это правильно, это необходимый процесс развития языка.  Да,  это, наверное,  правильно, когда такое РАЗВИТИЕ имеет место, а у нас очень часто имеет место не развитие, а ТОПТАНИЕ НА МЕСТЕ типа «кондУкторы – кондукторА».

Вариантные ударения должны находиться под пристальным вниманием науки, объясняющей суть развития акцентных форм.  Поэтому можно поставить вопрос о  рекомендательном выборе одного из равноправных сейчас вариантов в качестве основного.  Есть мнения, что многовариантность ударения  как факт   (а не как способ развития языка) мешает говорящему, заставляя его постоянно напрягаться, подбирая нормативный вариант, который еще не так просто отыскать. Поэтому акцентное единообразие для тех случаев, где это возможно,  –  насущное требование сегодняшнего дня.

Неужели так сложно для кодУкторов/кондукторОв  поставить стилистическую пометку на одном из вариантов, например:  кондУкторы (нейтр.) и кондукторА (разг.). Или  кондукторА (нейтр.) и кондУкторы (книжн.). Представляете, сколько ментальной энергии по всей стране можно  будет сэкономить.

Вопрос 2. Какой из существующих орфоэпических словарей  можно назвать академическим, то есть  таким, по которому должны сверяться все остальные издания орфоэпических словарей? И есть ли у нас такой словарь?

А) Орфоэпический словарь русского языка под ред. Аванесова (последнее издание 2000 год, причем оно фактически повторяет 1983 год).

Б) Орфографический (не орфоэпический!) словарь  РАН под ред. Лопатина.

В)  Новый  «Большой орфоэпический словарь русского языка» под редакцией Л.Касаткина. 2012 год «Кроме него, авторами являются уважаемые лингвисты Мария Каленчук и Розалия Касаткина. Все – из надежнейшего Института русского языка имени Виноградова РАН» (цитата).

Г) Другие словари, например: Зарва «Русское словесное ударение», 2001,  Введенская Л.  Словарь ударений для дикторов радио и телевидения. М., 2003,  словари И. Резниченко (практический материал соответствует орфографическому словарю Лопатина).

Спасибо за  ваше мнение.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Для определения четкости позиции предлагается условное голосование:

1) Я положительно оцениваю существование равноправных норм ударения.

Хотя  наличие таких вариантов никак не свидетельствует  о достоинствах   языка (как, например, наличие  синонимов),  я использую ту форму, которая мне удобна, и никто из очень грамотных  не будет меня поправлять.

2)Я отрицательно  оцениваю существование равноправных норм ударения.

Они  никак не повышают уровень развития языка, затрудняют его изучение и отвлекают внимание пользователей от более важных проблем (например, от умения грамотно и выразительно/эмоционально строить свою речь). Мне удобнее один раз заглянуть в словарь, чтобы уточнить правильный вариант.

Примечание. Речь идет о необоснованной вариативности, когда  развитие нормы  переходит в колебательный процесс.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Неужели так сложно для кодУкторов/кондукторОв поставить стилистическую пометку на одном из вариантов.

Совсем несложно, только проблема - а судьи кто? Люди сейчас живут сравнительно долго и то что воспринималось нормально 40 лет назад, для молодого поколения является устаревшим. Я, например, в устной речи ни разу не слышал слово "йогурт" с ударением на последний слог, однако до недавнего времени это было единственной нормой. Сейчас Зарва даёт правильным только привычный мне вариант с ударением на первый слог, но что делать человеку, который освоил слово по старой норме? Срочно переучиваться, чтобы успеть за порой довольно волюнтаристскими решениями составителей словарей? Или может словарям не менять норму до тех пор пока не вымрет последний представитель старого произношения? И тот и другой подход имеют массу недостатков, именно поэтому и распространён подход с двумя равноправными нормами.

Это не касаясь того, что в русском языке изначально несколько норм произношения. Не будете же вы петербуржскому профессору объяснять, что правильно *[дош:']*, а не *[дошт']*. Из моих знакомых только единицы смогли угадать в старомосковском [ч'и(э)т'в'Эр'х'] всем знакомый "четверг", а ведь это насколько понимаю тоже считается нормой, хоть сейчас так вряд ли кто говорит.

> Есть мнения, что многовариантность ударения как факт (а не как способ развития языка) мешает говорящему, заставляя его постоянно напрягаться, подбирая нормативный вариант, который еще не так просто отыскать.

А есть мнение, что вариативность норм позволяет людям осуществлять общение не задумываясь над тем насколько нормативным является тот или иной вариант. В итоге можно не задумываться идёшь ты по мостУ, пО мосту или по мОсту, по словарю Резниченко это три равноценных нормы.
Естественно для журналистов одной редакции должны действовать одинаковые нормы, для этих целей и предназначен словарь Зарвы, где везде дан только один вариант произношения.

> Какой из существующих орфоэпических словарей можно назвать академическим, то есть таким, по которому должны сверяться все остальные издания орфоэпических словарей? И есть ли у нас такой словарь?

Насколько знаю, на данный момент наиболее полным является «Большой орфоэпический словарь русского языка» под редакцией Л.Касаткина. 2012 Он единственный который на сегодня может претендовать, на звание современного академического орфоэпического словаря.

Comment: Представим такую ситуацию: слово имеет два равноправных ударения и, соответственно, равную частотность употребления.  В разговоре ваш собеседник употребил одну норму, а вы пользуетесь другой. Вы отвлекаетесь от беседы и начинаете думать, какое ударение правильное, точно ли возможны обе формы, а вдруг что-то изменилось. Теперь представим, что обе нормы существуют, но одна из них в академическом словаре помечена словом «рекомендуется». Тогда частотность употребления этой формы будет постоянно возрастать, а вероятность вашей встречи с «инакоговорящим» собеседником будет уменьшаться.

Comment: При этом никакого насилия над пользователями, только «мягкая» рекомендация в пользу одного из вариантов. И еще вопрос по словарю 2012 года: вы с ним работали, существует ли его электронная версия. Говорят, что в первом издании много издательского брака. И там, к моему сожалению, допускаются равноправные варианты

Comment: >В разговоре ваш собеседник употребил одну норму ... Вы ... начинаете думать, какое ударение правильное

Регулярно общался подобным образом, проблем в коммуникации не возникало. Если было интересно, заглядывал в словарь. Будь норма единственная - заглядывал бы реже.

>одна из них в академическом словаре помечена словом «рекомендуется». Тогда частотность употребления этой формы будет постоянно возрастать

Сомневаюсь. Ни разу не слышал единственно правильное по большинству словарей слово *предвосхИтить*, более того, боюсь, что если его употреблю, как на неграмотного будут смотреть на меня.

Comment: >И еще вопрос по словарю 2012 года: вы с ним работали, существует ли его электронная версия. Говорят, что в первом издании много издательского брака. И там, к моему сожалению, допускаются равноправные варианты.

Электронной версии не попадалось, и брака действительно много, поэтому и пишу, что единственный, который "может претендовать". Станет ли он таковым пока непонятно. К счастью, вариации там отмечены, что позволяет использовать грамотную речь представителям разных поколений и территорий.

Comment: Спасибо, Марк, за ответ. Жаль только, что у нас разные представления о счастье.

Comment: о, так это был диалог о счастье!..

Answer (score 2):

С кондуктором вообще дело трудно обстоит. В большом толковом словаре ( на Грамота.ру): 1. мн.: кондуктора, -ов; 3. мн.: кондуктор*а,* -ов. Техн. Там же , в словаре русского словесного ударения: кондуктор, -а; мн. кондуктор*а*, -ов (работник транспорта) и кондуктор*ы*, -ов (деталь машины). Кстати, вы,наверное, слышали, что государство утвердило специальный список грамматик и словарей,содержащих нормы русского языка. Только вот непонятно, кто отбирал эти словари и грамматики и на каком основании? [Ссылка](http://www.o-detstve.ru/forteachers/primaryschool/formalped/323.html)
http://www.svoboda.org/content/article/24929410.html  ;  Большой орфоэпический словарь русского языка под редакцией Леонида Касаткина. 
Можно еще почитать в интернете о словаре. 
Больше всего удивило новшество: слово "звОнит" дается с пометой "не рекомендуется". что получается тогда, так говорить можно, но мы( сотрудники института Ран) не рекомендуем. При некоторых словах, однако, как я понял, дается помета "не допустимо". Словарь почему-то так же рекомендует произносить только ГлУшит. Хотя в других словарях пока только глушИТ. В общем, словарь не идеален.

Марк, спасибо за сокращение ссылки. Я еще не научился делать такие ссылки.

Comment: >Я еще не научился делать такие ссылки

Tcnm 2 способа:

1. В окне ответа выделяете слово и  нажимаете на значок Земли, после чего в открывшееся окно вводите ссылку - энтер.

2. Слово гиперссылки помещаете в квадратные скобки и без пробела с "http://" в круглых скобках помещаете адрес страницы [Слово](адрес)

[Подробнее](http://russ.hashcode.ru/markdown_help/)

Comment: Этот список утвердил Фурсенко в 2009 году, он производит странное впечатление, да и непонятно кто им пользуется. (Интересно определена  область его применения: утвердить прилагаемый список грамматик, словарей и справочников, содержащих нормы современного русского литературного языка при его использовании в качестве государственного языка РФ).  А где же современные академические труды? Так и будем произношение контролировать по орфографическому словарю? Вот новый орфоэпический словарь 2012 года под ред. Касаткина кто-нибудь видел? Я только читала о нем не очень хвалебные отзывы.